# what is ftp username and password for vsftpd?

Tags: login, ftp, vsftpd

I installed VSFTPD on ubuntu 12.04, and now how do I log in? Which username and password do I use? I tried using root and the password for root, but that didn't work.

Comment: You get to choose a username and password at installation. If you can't remember those, you're going to need to reset the password

Answer (score 12):

If you installed with the default vsftpd configuration, then you should be able to login using any valid local user account on the target machine. If that doesn't work, then check that `local_enable=YES` is set in the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file and restart the vsftpd service.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT TURN ON `anonymous_enable=YES`
It might be provide security defect on you ftp enterance.

1. type `adduser YOURNEWUSERNAME` for create new identity on your system.
2. setup user list options
   `userlist_enable=YES userlist_deny=NO`
3. create `vsftpd.userlist` and add your user name to file.

It must make you available to login with your id and password

Answer (score -1):

Try turning on `anonymous_enable=YES` in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` and logging in as "anonymous" with any email.